# How get VS HTML editor to default to single quotes?

Tags: html, visual-studio, editor, autocomplete, intellisense

Autocompletion in the Visual Studio HTML editor inserts double quotes (e.g. `<input type="text"`).

Does anyone know if there's a setting that will change the default to automatically insert single quotes (e.g. `<input type='text'`)?

thanks, 
Michael

Comment: This is not XHTML compliant though.. why do you want single quotes?

Comment: @EvilSyn - This actually is compliant.  The Xml spec states that attribute values are quoted with single or double quotes.  The XHTML spec states that it must be a valid Xml document with some additional constraints.  Double quotes for attributes is not one of those constraints.

Comment: Wow! I always thought double quotes were required!

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this.  It's very useful if you want to embed databinding expressions in the XHTML of an asp.NET form.  Eg; <input runat="server" URL='<%# getURL(dataitem("ItemID")) %>' />

Comment: I'd love to know the answer. It has less visual load.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option built into Visual Studio to do this.  There might be a third party plugin to help you out, but if so I am not familiar with it.