# Can Visual Studio 2015 HTML editor insert single quotes for attributes?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am aware that a similar question was asked here: [How get VS HTML editor to default to single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270264/how-get-vs-html-editor-to-default-to-single-quotes), but it was never answered, and that was 7 years ago and a lot has changed.

I'm trying to get VS to automatically insert single quotes for HTML attributes instead of the standard double quotes. Is there any functionality or any extensions that would allow me to do this?

I know that I can prevent VS from inserting attribute value quotes in the options menu, but I am trying to see if there is a more efficient way to have single quotes for attributes rather than having to enter them every time.